# Expressão regular não detecta primeira entidade

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Essa expressão: `(?<=.*"")\s` não está detectando o primeiro espaço que deveria detectar:

```
<object name="Arrow" id="40" price="$400" description="Uma flecha comum.">
```

o correto seria detectar o seguinte:

```
 <object name="Arrow" id="40" price="$400" description="Uma flecha comum.">
        ^            ^       ^            ^
```

mas ta detectando isso:

```
 <object name="Arrow" id="40" price="$400" description="Uma flecha comum.">
                     ^       ^            ^
```

não detecta o que ta entre "object name".... Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 2):

Isso esta acontecendo divido as aspas depois do .*

```
(?<=.*)\s
```

No entanto você ainda terá que trabalhar nessa regex, pois desse modo irá capturar os espaços dentro do atributo descrição, coisa que você também não vai querer.

Comment: Então como eu coloco para não capturar o que estiver dentro de um valor?

Comment: O que você precisa exatamente? Você quer todos os atributos e valores dentro de uma tag? Preciso saber qual é a sua intenção para tentar te ajudar da melhor forma.

Comment: Preciso pegar o espaço que divide um atributo do outro, para fazer o `Regex.Split()` depois...

Comment: depois... o quê? Cada valor retornado está dentro de um Matcher Group que é um array das ocorrências que a REGEX encontrou, ou seja, você já em um array de cada attributo.. Qual a necessidade do Regex.Split()?

Comment: Eu quero pegar o que está no atributo, nome e valor, e para isso estou usando `Regex.Split` para retornar uma lista com os textos dos atributos, exemplo: "`teste_testando="valor do att"`"